# Finding a relatively compact open neighbourhood of a compact set

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be an open subset of $\mathbb R^N$ and $K$ be a compact subset of $X$. Show that there exists a relatively compact neighbourhood $U$ of $K$ such that $K\subset U\subset X$.

Since $\mathbb R^N$ is normal and compact set is closed there is an open set $U$ such that $K\subset U \subset X$ but how can we show that $U$ is relatively compact? i.e. $\bar U$ is compact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $x \in K$ there exists $r_x>0$ such that $\overline {B(x,r_x)}\subset X$. These balls cover $K$ and there is a finite subcover $\{B(x_i,r_{x_i}): 1 \leq i \leq n\}$. Let $U$ be the union of these balls. [Note that any bounded subset of $\mathbb R^{n}$ is relatively compact].